# Need helps in Motorola ATRIX

Tags: android

```
     I need Motorola ATRIX emulator skin for testing my application,anybody knows please give me.
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

You can find one here:
http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/tools/

Motorola ATRIX MB860 SDK Add-on

If you're not yet a MOTODEV member, you'll need to register.

Comment: download links have been broken, and yes I do log in ;)